# How to access a digital camera on .NET

Tags: .net, usb, camera, wia, twain

We're interested in accessing a digital camera from a .NET application, i.e., the users makes some photos, then connects the camera to a computer and automatically the system imports the photos and make some related questions.
What's the best way to do it?, TWAIN, WIA, WPD, USB directly?, any experiences?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: At least normally, when a user plugs in the camera it shows up as a disk drive with a directory named DCIM containing the pictures (possibly in subdirectories). I'd just wait for drives to appear, check if they contain that directory, and if so go from there...

Answer (score 0):

In practically all cases a digital camera appears as a Disk in the computer when it is connected via USB or FireWire, so it would be very easy to monitor a particular unit (E: for example) and if that unit appears launch a process that scans the folders and copy the new files to a given path.

If your camera is not detected as a drive when connected then you will be forced to use the SDK if there is one.